# Adding a Click event handler programmatically to a radio button

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I know for a button, I can do this:

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);
```

But how can I do it for a radio button?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
 radioButton1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(radioButton1_Click);


 private void radioButton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
this.button1.Checked += ...

this.button1.Unchecked += ...
```